# cant filter the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

why if try to consolelog mystate it always gave me the inintial value without change
iam tring to fillter the state using fillter but just keep giving the inintial value without any update
i try use effect but dosnt work

```
function Starts() {
  let [mystate, setmystate] = useState(perosns);
  let [temp, setTemp] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    let handler = () => {
      setmystate((prevdate) => {
        return prevdate.filter((Ele) =>  Ele.id !== temp);
      });
      console.log(mystate);
    };
    if (temp) {
      handler();
    }
  }, [temp]);

  return (
    <>
      <input onKeyUp={(e) => setTemp(e.target.value)} />
    </>
  );
}

export let perosns = [
  {
    id: "1",
    first_name: "Mollie",
    last_name: "Keppin",
    email: "mkeppin0@geocities.jp",
    gender: "Female",
    age: 49,
  },...
```

i tried to add some useEffect but still dosnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when you set a state, it doesn't update immediately. It's asynchronous.

Add this `useEffect` to log the result

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(mystate);
  }, [mystate]); // Add this useEffect
```